# laravel-localization hide default locale

Tags: laravel, localization, hide

I'm using Laravel-Localization 1.2.6 in Laravel 5.3

When I set:

```
hideDefaultLocaleInURL = true
```

It's not working.
locale is set to 'sk'
fallback_locale is set to 'sk'

But I can access both domain.app & domain.app/sk
Also when I switch language to SK language code is still in URL.
Everything else is working fine... Any suggestions?

Comment: This is defined in your routes right? So you need to remove the locale part of the url.

Comment: No this is defined in extension config

Answer (score 0):

Just clean your config cache
`php artisan config:cache`